# Am I understanding this alright? あの武器のプレイは、皆さんが想像している通りのものになると思います

Tags: translation, word-choice

I was reading an interview from a game magazine and I'm not sure if I understand what the director of a game is saying when he was asked a question. He was asked if he could tell some details about some weapons, how will will the gameplay be like, but he does not answer directly because he did not want to reveal more information, saying that us players should wait a little longer.
The director says:

> あの武器のプレイは、皆さんが想像している通りのものになると思います.

I don't know if I am translating properly. Is it: "I think I will let the gameplay of those weapons be up to everyone's imagination" OR "I think the gameplay is what everyone imagines."
Also, not sure if it would be the same, but I wanted at first to use "expectation" as in, "the gameplay is what everyone expects", but the word is not 期待している.

Pretty sure I am misunderstanding, so I hope someone can help me out.　Also, is
ものになる the same as ことになる？

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you've written, I think this is the clause you're having trouble with:

> 皆が想像している通りのものになる 
> will be what everyone imagines it to be.

I don't really understand why you think has to be 期待 here, but 想像する can be used similarly to mean "imagine" or "expected". So in that case:

> 想像している通り

just means "as imagined". And then if you append のもの to the end of this phrase, you get:

> 想像している通りのもの
>
>  what (everyone) imagines it to be.

and then adding になる to the end of that clause you get:

> 想像している通りのものになる 
> will be what (everyone) imagines it to be.

So we've come full circle. When you put this into the context of the entire sentence, it just becomes:

> あの武器のプレイは、**皆さんが想像している通りのものになる**と思います.
>
>  I think the way the weapon is played **will be what everyone imagines it to be**.

So I think your second translation was pretty close to what what the sentence tries to express. To address the difference between もの and こと, the basic difference between the two is that もの is used for more concrete nouns while こと is more abstract.

> 分かるということはどういうことでしょうか。〇
>
>  分かるというものはどういうものでしょうか。☓
>
>  What does understanding really mean?

You wouldn't be able to use もの here because "understanding" is not a tangible thing. It is an abstract idea. The same can be applied when you are choosing between ものになる and ことになる.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped a lot! The difference with こと and もの as well, I thought it had to do with politeness. Than you for explaining!

Comment: @AliceB.Rabbit You're welcome! I want to note that this rule of もの being always concrete is not a definite rule. Although in a lot of cases this does work, Japanese considers things like 愛 as もの, not こと. Although 愛というもの is valid, 愛ということ is not. I don't know if there is a list of these or not, but there are plenty of words that fall into もの despite being "concrete".

Answer (score 1):

I think the both provided translations in English are quite similar, so it is pretty difficult to decide which one is better. The key point in the sentence is *ものになる* which means that *it will become*. According to my knowledge an appropriate translation could be

> Gameplay of the weapon will become the same as everyone imagines, I think.

想像 sounds more poetical than 期待, so I think that the director opted for 想像 because of this reason.
もの and こと(事) mean the same thing, except こと is more polite and usually used in keigo sentences. Another difference is もの is used for tangible objects while こと is used for intangible ones.

I hope I was able to clarify something.